# How to solve PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_required, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4: , null))

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error when I use google_sign_in plugin
the code is as follows

```
googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
  handleSignIn(account);
  print(account);
}).catchError((err) {
  print('error signing in :$err');
});
```

error:
[image: le]

Comment: Look into this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33393#issuecomment-510395178

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vs code.. uncheck the uncaught exceptions in the breakpoints tab at the bottom left.